# Yeoman angularjs build error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I install yeoman and bootstrap an angularjs project.

I use `grunt server` command to debug and code. But when I use command 'grunt build'. It generates dist folder. But when I run index.html have javascript error like that:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/cuongcua/project/magic-listen/dist/views/main.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grunt server:build`

You can't use AngularJs without server except if you enable CSP (Content Security Policy) support.
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCsp

`grunt build` is use when you need to build your application and copy your dist folder on a server.

Comment: I don't understand much about that. If I want to build it on server like github page or S3 what should I need? I mean my project completely on client with js, and html.

Comment: If you want to build it on server like github page or S3, you should run grunt build. After you just need to copy dist folder to your server, and you shouldn't have Cross origin requests error.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is:

```
cd dist
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```